# boost::async_write fails after writing for some time

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I am having a very peculiar problem. I have written a server that writes data that it receives from a third party to connected clients. The server writes to the client(s) fine for a while, but after a while, async_write either fails or a write never returns. For my program, if an async_write never returns, then no subsequent writes will take place, and my server will queue up the data it receives from the third party until everything blows up.

I have included my code below:

```
void ClientPartitionServer::HandleSignal(const CommonSessionMessage& message, int transferSize) {
  boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
  if(m_clientSockets.size() != 0) {
    TransferToQueueBuffer(message.GetData(), transferSize);
  }
  if(m_writeCompleteFlag) {
    // TransferToWriteBuffer();
    for(vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket*>::const_iterator i = m_clientSockets.begin(); i != m_clientSockets.end(); ++i) {
      WriteToClient(*i);
    }
  }
}

void ClientPartitionServer::WriteToClient(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* clientSocket) {
  m_writeCompleteFlag = false;
  cout << "Iniating write: " << m_identifier << endl;
  boost::asio::async_write(
    *clientSocket,
    boost::asio::buffer(m_queueBuffer.get(), m_queueBufferSize),
    boost::bind(
      &ClientPartitionServer::HandleWrite, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
  ));
}

void ClientPartitionServer::HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
  boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
  if(ec != 0) {
    cerr << "Error writing to client: " << ec.message() << " " << m_identifier << endl;
    // return;
    cout << "HandleWrite Error" << endl;
    exit(0);
  }
  cout << "Write complete: " << m_identifier << endl;
  m_writeCompleteFlag = true;
  m_queueBuffer.reset();
  m_queueBufferSize = 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Mutexes with async I/O are NO NO

Comment: Use ASIO strands instead. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html for an example and details.

Comment: If you are sure that async_write never returns, then it is a bug in asio, because async_write is documented to return immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing all the code it's hard to say, but it's a red flag to me that you hold the mutex across multiple (or even one) `WriteToClient` calls.  Typically holding a lock of any kind across I/O (even async as you have here) is at best bad for performance and at worst a recipe for weird deadlocks under load.  What happens if the async write completes inline and you get called back on `HandleWrite` in the same thread/callstack, for instance?

I would try to refactor this so that the lock is released during the write calls.

Whatever the solution turns out to be, more general advice:

- don't lock across I/Os
- add some diagnostic output - what
  thread calls each handler, and in
  what order?
- try debugging once you hit the
  quiescent state.  Should be able
  to diagnose a deadlock from the
  process state.

Comment: However, my program may have concurrent calls to the async_write code block as well as write input to the queue that holds the data to write out. If I don't protect these code blocks with mutexes, then how am I supposed to protect against data corruption from concurrent input/output being performed on the same data?

Comment: +1 for don't lock across I/O operations. @czchlong read about strands, see [Sean's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143739/boostasync-write-fails-after-writing-for-some-time/6158561#615856).

Comment: I don't see that holding locks across IO is a problem.  What is usually a problem is holding locks across blocking operations, and holding locks across callbacks.  So the question is whether asio does any sort of callbacks inside async_write, or if async_write can block.  From reading the documentation, async_write gives both guarantees.  It must immediately return, and the handler is guaranteed not to be called from within async_write.

Answer (score 1):

Use strands to serialize access to particular connection objects. In particular, check out [strand::wrap()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html). To see other examples of using strands, check out a a [few different](https://github.com/sean-/Boost.Examples/blob/master/asio/timer/timer.cc#L77) [timer examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) (though the code works for any `async_*()` call).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't agree with the comments indicating that holding locks across an async operation is a problem.

Holding locks across:

1. Any function that invokes callbacks is bad.
2. Any blocking operation is bad.

`async_write` explicitly guarantees to neither block, nor call the handler, so it looks good to me to hold the lock.

However, I can see a bug in your code that violates another requirement that `async_write` has.  You are not allowed to call `async_write` until the completion handler has been invoked.  That's what you violate.

The `m_writeCompleteFlag` is set to `true` whenever *one of the handlers* have been invoked.  This means that you are likely to violate the `async_write` rules for some of the other N-1 sockets under high load.