# boost::asio threadpool vs. io_service_per_cpu design

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, threadpool

Currently I´m not sure, I try to make a high-performance server, I got a 6Core CPU, so if I would use the "io_service_per_cpu" design, I have 6 io_service´s.

I already heard that the threadpool design isn´t the best one, but I´m not sure about that.

What knowledge do you have? Someone already made a Stress test with each, or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience it is vastly easier to approach asynchronous application design with the following order:

1. single thread and a single `io_service`
2. multiple threads, each invoking `io_service::run()` from a single `io_service`. Use [strands](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) for handlers that require access to shared data structures.
3. `io_service` per cpu

The motivation for changing between each of these designs should be done after profiling your application. Note that the [HTTP Server 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143739/boostasync-write-fails-after-writing-for-some-time/6158561#6158561) example only shows how to use an `io_service` per CPU, it does not show you when or why to use such a design.

Answer (score 5):

Another good way to approach this: start up multiple copies of your process and bind each one to a different core using your OS'es. For FreeBSD, use [`cpuset`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset&sektion=0). The OS is going to do a better job than any userland code will. Then you need to use an external load balancer to distribute load across your server instances. Extra points for binding a NIC interrupts to a particular CPU.